# mdadm raid5 error during reshape

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, raid5

I first had a working 3 drive array (3 x 6TB drives) and added a 4th. It added as a spare so i ran the grow command. During this the machine rebooted and it did not recognize the 4th drive when it booted back up.

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm --grow raid-devices=4 /dev/md0
```

Whenever i assemble the drive the reshape speed starts at 2245k/sec and slowly slows to 0k/sec. It is on 0% complete.

I have tried starting the array in readonly mode. As if i assemble it normally all my mdadm
commands referring to /dev/md0 freeze and i cant do anything in the terminal.

Is there a way to revert the reshape and go back to 3 drives?

Can i just build/create the array again with the original 3 drives?

Comment: or even, is there a way to mount it so i can get the more important data off?

Comment: mdadm version? kernel version? anything in dmesg? mdadm --examine? it should be mountable and work normally even during reshape, but you might be either hitting some kernel bug or some different hardware problem.